# HTML Images are misalign on chrome and safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

Im been trying to make my page work on different browsers and its seems it only works on IE and in other browser all my images are misalign. im not really good at HTML and its been awhile since the last time I use html, please check my codes below. And i need my page to be 640 x 480 px. Thanks

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AD</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <div style="{z-index:3;}">
<img src="images/Header.gif" width="640" height="110"
/div>
<div style="{position: absolute; top: 145; left: 310; z-index:3;} font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; color:#000000;">at</div>

<div style="{position: absolute; top: 115; right: 185; z-index:3;}">
<img src="images/Brush.gif" width="100" height="215"
</div>
<div style="{position: absolute; top: 20; right: 145; z-index:3;}">
<img src="images/LOGO.gif" width="330" height="85"
</div>
<tr>

    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#f0f8ff" style="background-color:#f0f8ff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000000; padding:8px;"><table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top:10px;">
```

```
<center> text 1 <br><b>Competitive text2
<br>text3</b>
<br></center></div></td>
<br>
<center> <div style="font-size=20px;"> text4
<br>text5K.<br>
          </center></div>
<br>

  </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
 <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#00000" style="background-color:#00000;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7">
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;"> <center><b>Apply online today at <font color=#6699ff> &nbsp;<a href="http://www.startek.com/careers/" style="text-decoration: none; color:#6699ff;">www.startek.com/careers</a></font></b>

</td>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;"> <center>address
<br><b>tel.no.</b>
</td>

      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use css for different kind of browser, look for more information:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml

Comment: I tried to pretty-indent your code, but it's so malformed that I can't...

Comment: ^ I agree. If you want to develop software whether web or pc do proper indentation.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you see the problem? Try to elaborate a bit, instead of posting "fix my stuff for me" questions.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of CSS layout elements such as `position`. Your code just works on some browsers because some formatting is not cross browser compatible.

I advise you to use CSS for formatting because some of the HTML formatting you use are already deprecated. Here is a nice [CSS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was also with me...Since HTML output may vary depending upon the browser, you should use adobe dreamweaver.It has a functionality to output HTML same in all browser by default...by the way..how it does i don't know.

If you can't afford dreamweaver right now..make sure you include `position` attribute in 
div tag properly.

try like this:

```
<div position=absolute>main panel</div>
```